# Sum matrix error octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, octave

I start from a matrix of the shape: N · 2 · M which I call it as x. Then, I have another matrix called theta of the shape M. The following code give me the following error in octave: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x2x2, op2 is 2x2x2).

```
  x(n+1,:,:) = x(n+1,:,:) + [cos(theta(:)) sin(theta(:))]
```

what is wrong with it?

PS. Here is the complete code:

```
M=30;
N=32;

for n=1:1:N
    z = [1.0 0.0]
    x(1,1,1:M) = z(1);
    x(1,2,1:M) = z(2);

    x(n+1,:,:) = x(n,:,:) + randn([1,2,M])
    theta(:) = randn([M,1]);
    x(n+1,:,:) = x(n+1,:,:) + [cos(theta(:)) sin(theta(:))]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size([cos(theta(:)) sin(theta(:))])` is 30x2 while `size(x(n+1,:,:))` is 1x2x30

They don't match.

I do not know if this is mathematically what you need (i.e. if the indices that get added together are the ones that should), but you can fix this by doing:

```
 x(n+1,:,:) = x(n+1,:,:) + reshape([cos(theta(:)) sin(theta(:))].',1,2,M);
```

Comment: I see... I was using M=2 and the matrix was 2x2 and 2x2. Isn't that strange?

Comment: @Learningfrommasters The second one was 1x2x2, to be precise

Comment: Isn't this way a correct way to upload a submatrix? Actually if I do A = x(n+1,:,:); B=[cos(theta(:)) sin(theta(:))]; A+B is working but x(n+1,:,:)=A+B no

Comment: @Learningfrommasters no, they need to be the same size

Comment: The easy way to fix it is to change `x` to be 2xMxN. Then `x(:,:,n+1)` will be the right shape.